# API Calls bombs in loop when object not found

Tags: python, api

My code is erroring out when the object "@odata.nextLink" is not found in the JSON. I thought the while loop was supposed to account for this? I apologize if this is rudimentary but this is my first python project, so i dont know the stuffs yet.

Also, for what it is worth, the api results are quite limited, there now "total pages" value I can extract

[image]

```
# Import Python ODBC module
import pyodbc
import requests
import json
import sys

cnxn = pyodbc.connect(driver="{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}",server="theplacewherethedatais",database="oneofthosedbthings",uid="u",pwd="pw")
cursor = cnxn.cursor()

storedProc = "exec GetGroupsAndCompanies"

for irow in cursor.execute(storedProc):

    strObj = str(irow[0])
    strGrp = str(irow[1])
    print(strObj+" "+strGrp)
    response = requests.get(irow[2], timeout=300000, auth=('u', 'pw')).json()
    data = response["value"]
    while response["@odata.nextLink"]:
        response = requests.get(response["@odata.nextLink"], timeout=300000, auth=('u', 'pw')).json()
        data.extend(response["value"])

cnxn.commit()
cnxn.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `in` keyword to test if a key is present:

```
while "@odata.nextLink" in response:
```